# Working with maven and multiple git repositories

Tags: java, git, maven

We recently migrated from SVN, with most code in a single repo, to git, with most projects in their own repos (about 70 of them).
We build about a dozen different apps from this java source. The apps all run on *nix servers.
We use maven and nexus to build.
Many of us are struggling with developing features when that feature touches more than one repo.  Here are a few of the challenges:

- The developer has to branch each repo separately - we use the same name for all branches for one feature to make tracking less difficult.
- One must update poms of all repos to point to the updated versions of each repo's artifact.  If multiple people are working on the same branch, there can be a lot of merging others pom changes. When I commit a change to a repo, then the artifact is renamed to "-SNAPSHOT" which means *more* pom updates.
- Changes need to be pushed in the right order or our automated builds will fail, e.g: repo A depends on a change to repo B; if repo A is pushed before repo B is built and deployed, then repo A won't build.
- The person reviewing the feature has to look at changes in multiple repos.
- When the feature is merged from its branch to, say, master, One has to remember all the repos that were touched.

It looks like switching to a mostly monorepo approach might be best, tho there are some drawbacks there:

- Building the entire codebase with maven takes a looong time. (Why can't maven be more like make, only building things that have changed or whose dependencies have changed?)
- Each push kicks off a big set of builds and many unit tests rather than just one repo's artifact build and test.
- The developers who generally work in one or two repos prefer this new multi-repo world and will resist a change back.

I've looked into git submodules and sub trees, which don't *seem* to solve many of our issues (Not sure about Google Repo). Some of us use tools like "mu" to help.
It would be sweet if there was a toolkit that would help developers maintain versions in poms, and track changes across repos.

Let me know if you have a set of procedures or tools you use to ease development in this kind of environment.

Comment: I think a reason behind the push for having multiple repositories exists, though you may not agree.  A new system may be awkward but necessary.  Try to automate all the policies you can and for the ones you can't, make sure everyone knows the proper procedure.  Having a single repository in my experience tends to result in every project depending on every other project.  Not ever a good idea.

Comment: One of the teams I work with recently tried this unsuccessfully (my team is managing it nicely). The problem for them was that their repos weren't sufficiently modular, and frequently they would need to modify a large number of them even a simple change. Basically, before you go multi-repo, you should go fully modular in a mono-repo, so that when you break up into a multi-repo, your code is nicely modular and changes typically only affect a small number of repos.

Answer (score 4):

It might not be a direct answer, but I have the feeling these are more the symptoms than the "disease".

If I may, I think the main issue is that a feature implies touching so many different projects. I know we don't live in an ideal world, but perhaps putting aside the technical details and increasing the "low coupling / high cohesion" of your different projects may be an interesting goal.

If several projects are so tighly coupled that they are always touched together, put them together in a common repo. If a big chunk of code can be extracted as relatively independent library, do so.

Perhaps the most pragmatic approach is neither "each small project in a repo" nor "a giant monorepo with everything" but something in-between where closely related projects are bundled together in a repo, while relatively independent ones stay in their repos.

Comment: I agree with your answer and want to formulate it a bit differently: 
If the software is so closely coupled (in other words *monolithic*), it does not make sense splitting it into different Git-repositories.
Before migrating anything to Git, you should probably decouple it first and make the application more *Micro-Service-like*.